# Wine: 0024:err:process:exec_process L"" not supported on this system

Tags: wine, nix, games

I'm attempting to run `Among Us.exe` on my machine with Wine but I keep experiencing the same issue:

```bash
0024:err:process:exec_process L"Z:\\home\\runner\\Games\\AmongUs\\Among Us.exe" not supported on this system
```

I have no idea why this is happening since this is the first time I'm using Wine and other people are not experiencing this issue.

#### Debug Information

**Operating System**: Ubuntu, using nix packages: `wine64`, `wine64Packages.stableFull`
**EXE File**: [https://filebin.net/goipz1hqostcdb51\](https://filebin.net/goipz1hqostcdb51%5C)
I can provide anything else needed

Comment: I think that the issue is that `wine64` is used only for 64bit binaries (and even in that case it seems not really recommended to use it according to the wine team, it's mostly useful when you have a program that uses a **lot** of RAM). The error you have could be caused by the program being compiled for 32 bit architecture. Could you try `wineWowPackages.stable` as recommended by the wiki? Also, your file link is broken so I can't test myself. Finally, steam also provides among us with a native linux version (no wine), so you may be able to play among us using steam instead.

Comment: PS: next time you may want to try https://discourse.nixos.org for your question, nixos people are mostly on this website.